# swift NSMutableArray shuffle

Tags: arrays, swift, shuffle

I've found this code to shuffle an array:

```
func shuffle<T>(inout array: [T]) {
    for i in 1..<array.count {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i)))
        (array[i], array[j]) = (array[j], array[i])
    }
}
```

which works fine with

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
shuffle(&arr)
println(arr)
```

But how do I use with a `NSMutableArray`?
I've tried

```
 var PicturesArray :NSMutableArray = []

 shuffle(PicturesArray)as Array
 shuffle([PicturesArray])
 shuffle(PicturesArray[])
```

but can't find any answers probably something I'm doing silly
thanks for looking

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/e11a9fd983a115074b8e for example of Fisher-Yates shuffle of `NSMutableArray` in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it.

```
var arr = NSMutableArray(array: [1,2,3,4,5])
var arr_ = arr as [AnyObject]

shuffle(&arr_)
```

---

```
shuffle(PicturesArray)as Array // This is syntax error
shuffle([PicturesArray])       // This will make a new array with only one object inside
shuffle(PicturesArray[])       // This is also syntax error
```

Comment: hi you guys a so dam quick this gives an  error                                      [AnyObject]' is not convertible to 'inout [T]'

Comment: Yes I ran it in playground after I answered, checkout my update.